# How to read in words from file into a string

Tags: java

for a lab i am working on, we are supposed to read in words from a file and get the length of each, and then store it in an array. Would reading in each word into a string and then storing the length in the array be the best way of going about this? And if so, could someone give me a pointer on how to do this? I am a bit lost..

Thanks!

Comment: start by writing some code

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: Ok thanks! appreciate the pointers

Answer (score 1):

For simple data processing I suggest you use the Streams API

```
int[] wordLengths = 
   // get all the lines of the file as a stream.
   Files.lines(Paths.get("filename"))
        // split the lines into a stream of words
        .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.trim().split(" +")))
        // get the length of each word
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        // turn them into an array.
        .toArray();
```

Comment: Im not sure if I have learned how to use that API yet. I am only in CS2.

Comment: @Adam7397 I don't know what CS2 is but if your are expected to use what you have been taught, only you know what that is.

Comment: ok thanks! I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Adam7397 in short, I would use an array of `int`

Comment: Beautiful solution. A good demonstration of the Streams API.